# Excel Workbook Opens On Only The Second Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am working on a current project with Excel VBA, and it involves opening a pre-existing workbook with content already on it.  I'm not doing anything particularly complex, only copying content from the other workbook and pasting it in the workbook that I already had open.  At any rate, when I open the workbook with VBA, it opens it on the second Worksheet, regardless of what I change my code to, which is confusing because there was a point that the code I have now worked just fine, but now it seems to be broken for whatever reason; here's the format of it as it was before it broke:

```
With Workbooks.Open(fileName:="C:\Users\u333161\Desktop\HGIs\GVII-G600 Stress Report Burndown Master  (plus GSNs) 3Q Rev 8-22 update.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True).Range("A1:X2500") 
    'All the content that the script contains is here'
End With
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated; thanks so much and have a great afternoon.

For those of you that wanted the content in between the With statements, this is it:

```
With Workbooks.Open(fileName:="C:\Users\u333161\Desktop\HGIs\GVII-G600 Stress Report Burndown Master  (plus GSNs) 3Q Rev 8-22 update.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True).Worksheets(1).Range("A1:X2500")
'Opens the G600 Burndown from the original location ^
.AutoFilter                                                                         'Clears any filters on the document
.AutoFilter 20, "y"                                                                 'Sets "Cert Doc" to filter for "y"
.AutoFilter 13, ""                                                                  'Sets "Release Date" to (blanks)
.Rows.Sort Key1:=Columns("I"), Order1:=xlAscending                                  'Sets "3Q Replan" to sort "Oldest To Newest"
Dim columnRange As Range, cell As Range, comparingDate As Range                     'Declares variables
Set columnRange = Range("I1: I2500")                                                'Sets a variable equal to a range
For Each cell In columnRange                                                        'Loop to go through all the rows in the "I" column
  If CDate(cell.Value) > Now() Then                                                 'Compares each date in the "I" column to today
    Range("A1:X" & cell.Offset(-1, 0).Row).Copy                                     'Copies the entire range above the current if the date for the current row happens after today
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Exit For                                                                        'Terminates the for loop because there is no reason to keep looping
  End If                                                                            'End of the if statement
Next cell                                                                           'Goes to the next cell
End With                                                                              'We're done with this sheet, so we can end it
```

Comment: Did you tried activating/assigning the proper Worksheet before execution? Also the rest of the code might be helpful.

Comment: What happens if you manually open that file? If you need a different sheet to be activated, you need to have the code activate it. That said, you should try to avoid relying on activate.

Comment: Can you specify the sheet too? `With Open (...).Sheets(1).Range("A1:X2500")`?

Comment: I meant to mention that as well cybernetic.nomad... If I open the file myself, it also opens on the second Worksheet. Sorry about that.

Comment: I did try to do that Pm Duda and BruceWayne, and it worked with that as well before it broke.  I included that after it stopped working, and it didn't make a difference which one opened.

Comment: Sorry, so is your problem that the second worksheet is opening, or that *after* you open the file correctly, it crashes?

Comment: My problem is that it is opening on the second sheet to begin with, rather than the first, even when I'm specifying that I need the first sheet to be opened.  It doesn't crash at all.

Comment: It usually opens to the same sheet it was on when it was last saved. Try making some minor edit, then going to the sheet you want and saving the file.

Comment: Try with this: `Workbooks.Open(fileName:="C:\Users\u333161\Desktop\HGIs\GVII-G600 Stress Report Burndown Master  (plus GSNs) 3Q Rev 8-22 update.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True) Worksheets(1).Activate With Range("A1:X2500") `

Comment: That worked flawlessly Pm Duda, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected in comments, but to clarify what's wrong:

`With Workbooks.Open(fileName:="C:\Users\u333161\Desktop\HGIs\GVII-G600 Stress Report Burndown Master  (plus GSNs) 3Q Rev 8-22 update.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True).Worksheets(1).Range("A1:X2500")`

Here you specify a Workbook to open and it opens on "default" worksheet. Worksheet specification is used for `With` statement, not for `Workbook.Open`.

First you work with your `With`, but at some point you begin to work on active worksheet:

`Set columnRange = Range("I1: I2500")`

So you need to activate proper worksheet first:

```
Workbooks.Open(fileName:="C:\Users\u333161\Desktop\HGIs\GVII-G600 Stress Report Burndown Master (plus GSNs) 3Q Rev 8-22 update.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True) 
Worksheets(1).Activate 
With Range("A1:X2500")
```